# Getting wrong position from view

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer, baseadapter

I have a list view in which I have songs comes from service in a list ever row has button which is (Play/Pause) Button. I am having a problem on On complete of songs because if my Song ends then I want to perform click on Next row play button but it performs click on the 4th row button. but if I increase the height of the list row than it plays the second one. I am also trying to use method setTag() And getTag() but no luck.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Planet planet = (Planet) planetList.get(position);


        viewHolder = null;

        // Create a new row view
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contexts.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows_relative, parent, false);

            viewHolder.playbutton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);

            }
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

    viewHolder.playbutton.setTag(position_tag);     //position_tag is a int variable


viewHolder.playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final int positiont = mainListView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                    String name = planet.getSong_url();

                    selectedPosition = positiont;
                    position_tag=selectedPosition;
                    position_tag=position_tag+1; // if i use this it gives error on complete button perform click

       position_tag=1; // if i use this then it plays second song perform second button click

        playsong(name);});}



mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                int hell = position_tag;
                Log.d("position_on",hell+"");  //aFTER 1st SONG COMPLETE these value prints "4" but i need next one  

                    viewHolder.checkBox.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01).findViewWithTag(position_tag).performClick();
                }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you getting the position from from mainListView.getPositionForView(). You already tag the positionto playbutton. then you can get the position from the play button. then, get song name from the list item , based on the button position click.

Comment: i also try these final int position = (Integer) v.getTag(); instead of  getPositionForView() ;  but i have performing so much things on play button so that's why i need to perform button click,on song complete , but @ahmed why these code working fo android Tv beacuse Tv list rows is bigger in height and mobile having small height rows.. Any idea??

Comment: And one more thing, Mediaplayer should be run as service. otherwise, player will stop playing when you exit the app.

Comment: thnku for the info man!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you should do like below,

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Planet planet = (Planet) planetList.get(position);


    viewHolder = null;

    // Create a new row view
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contexts.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows_relative, parent, false);

        viewHolder.playbutton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);



    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

viewHolder.playbutton.setTag(position);     //position_tag is a int variable


 viewHolder.playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final int positiont = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            PlanetList planet=planetList.get(positiont)
                String name = planet.getSong_url();

                selectedPosition = positiont;
               position_tag=positiont;
    playsong(name);});}



 mplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
       position_tag=(position_tag+1)
   final Planet planet = (Planet) planetList.get(position_tag);//UPDATED
   mp.setDataSource(planet.getSongUrl());
   mp.start();

            }
    });
```

**UPDATE**

create static field named position_tag then assigned the first position on button click, when the media player is completed, you can add +1 with position_tag, and check that position is still exist on the list item. then, and add it to the media player. set the URL to the MP then again start the mediaplayer with the same reference on mediaplayer completed listener.

**NOTE** : you are creating MediaPlayer object in adapter class, when the adapter class destroy  and recreated, the recreated mediaplayer object will not work on existing playing media file.

Comment: I try these two but it results same. On media complete my position is auto incremented with if its 1 then incremented and perform click on 5th row button.

Comment: So, what you want to do is, after complete the first song, it will automatically play the next song.right?ex: if the 1st song is playing next will be 2nd song should play right?

Comment: Yes i want these one bro . and my second row button changes from play to pause and the play button function calls like marquee highlight.

Comment: and what i put inside findViewWithTag(position_tag) ; istead of postion_tag ? position!!?

Comment: updated with existed answer. check on this. here position_tag is int type in your adapter class.

Comment: where do i increment my position_tag ? if i incremt position in on Complete then app crashes on theses line viewHolder.checkBox.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01).findViewWi‌​thTag(position_tag).‌​performClick();

Comment: i don't why my app crashes if i use increment operator with position_tag !!! if i put position_tag=2 , then its play the second song

Comment: apologise. i forgot to increment the position. now check on mediaplayer listener.

Comment: bro, i dont know why but adding number into position_tag crashes app on these line viewHolder.checkBox.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01).findViewWithTag(position_tag).performClick();

Comment: 'boolean android.view.View.performClick()' on a null object reference

Comment: why are stick with that line. i think that is no need. it is saying that the view cannot found. because you did't tag the position on checkbox. without set the tag, you are getting the tag. so the error appears.

Comment: sounds great. Happy coding.

Comment: Kindly dont forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please Change one line into getView , it  Should solved your problem.

```
 final Planet planet = (Planet)this.getItem(position);
```

Because When you click an `ListView` item its given position from visible list item size , And not from whole size in ordered way.

Also put below line into "if"clause which you are using to set tag .because you are change each time updated tag into view thats given all wage new position not actual  position which was set at first time inflate of listview .

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) contexts.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows_relative, parent, false);

        viewHolder.playbutton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.playbutton.setTag(position);     //position is a int variable    
    } else {    
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: getting this error @Chetan : java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to Planet , Plane is my Pojo Class.

Comment: @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }  This is my getItem.

Comment: if you are using ArrayAdapter<Planet > then ist should give Planet  object ,

Comment: Then ignore fist line and see getView "if" clause in which i put set tag line into "if" clause , Because each time tag value is changed in your code.

Comment: i am using Base Adapter and ArrayList<Planet> planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>(); this is my list.

Comment: i also try to setTag(Postion) it works but for my Tv app not for Mobile which have smaller rows in height.

Comment: now tried i put set Tag into if else but it gives null on Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.View.performClick()

Comment: you should add tag into if block not in else and use  viewHolder.playbutton.setonClickListene .

Comment: can you little bit explain @joshi i am not getting you.

Comment: In getView() method we are inflating views and using ViewHolder Design pattern to avoid view creation each time while scrolling . 

you already implemented ViewHolder  in right way in if block you first check if convertview is null then you created and set tag into convertview as viewholder object reference.

Comment: So at the same time if you are set tag position into ImageView before setTag inot convert view then it will stored for future use , but you must get tag from clicked view in onclick method .

Comment: viewHolder.playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final int positiont = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            PlanetList planet=planetList.get(positiont)
                String name = planet.getSong_url();

                selectedPosition = positiont;
    playsong(name);});}

Comment: thnx  i do it!! now on complete it performs click on first button again , where do i increment my position_tag ? if i incremt position in on Complete then app crashes on theses line viewHolder.checkBox.findViewById(R.id.CheckBox01).findViewWithTag(position_tag).performClick();

Comment: i don't why my app crashes sir if i use increment operator with position_tag !!! if i put position_tag=2 , then its play the second song

Comment: I updated my code !! now what issue i had.. i explain it

Comment: Have you  change BaseAdapter to ArrayAdapter

Comment: Add   viewHolder.playbutton.setTag(position); into if block

Comment: what to write in if statement block?

Comment: viewHolder.playbutton.setTag(position);

before

  convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

Answer (score 0):

In your viewHolder.playbutton.setOnClickListener you can get position of the clicked item using the viewholder's getAdapterPosition() method. In the onClickListener you can save that position and in onCompletionListener just increase this position by 1 and play the song from next row item.

Comment: yeah i do the same you said sir but i don't know why in on complete method my value which i increment is auto incremented with 4 numbers.